# How to use expressions for steps in azure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm little confused. Below code:

```
pool:
  vmImage: "macos-10.15"

trigger:
- none

steps:
- bash: |
    echo "##[section](var)"
    echo $(IMAGE)
    echo "##[section](expresion)"
    echo ${{ upper('${{variables.IMAGE}}') }}
    echo ${{ upper('$[variables.IMAGE]') }}
    echo ${{ upper('$(IMAGE)') }}
    echo ${{ upper(variables.IMAGE) }}
    echo ${{ upper('macos-latest') }}
```

generates:

```
(var)
macos-latest
(expresion)
/Users/runner/work/_temp/b6ca094a-8d4e-4405-b3eb-39ebe5aa993c.sh: line 5: ${{VARIABLES.IMAGE}}: bad substitution
/Users/runner/work/_temp/b6ca094a-8d4e-4405-b3eb-39ebe5aa993c.sh: line 6: VARIABLES.IMAGE: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".IMAGE")
macos-latest

MACOS-LATEST
```

So only expression invoked inside ${{ }} "works" but not as it should be.

What is wrong with my reasoning? What am I doing wrong?
Why `echo ${{ upper('$(IMAGE)') }}` does not return **MACOS-LATEST**?

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58267591/using-runtime-expressions-in-azure-pipelines-yaml-script).

### Edit

I give up. I don't have any idea how to make it work.

New sample. The pipeline:

```
pool:
  vmImage: "ubuntu-20.04"

trigger:
  - none

variables:
  - name: TEST_VAR
    value: test var

steps:
  - bash: |
      echo "##[group]Static text"
      echo "##[section]Compile time static text"
      echo ${{ upper('Static text') }}
      echo "##[section]Runtime static text"
      echo $[ upper('Static text') ]
      echo "##[endgroup]"

      echo "##[group]Static variable"
      echo "##[section]Compile time"
      echo ${{ upper(variables.TEST_VAR) }}
      echo ${{ upper(variables['TEST_VAR']) }}
      echo "##[section]Runtime"
      echo $[ upper("$(TEST_VAR)") ]
      echo $[ upper('$(TEST_VAR)') ]
      echo $[ upper($(TEST_VAR)) ]
      echo $[ upper(variables.TEST_VAR) ]
      echo $[ upper(variables['TEST_VAR']) ]
      echo "##[endgroup]"

      echo "##[group]Dynamic variable"
      echo "##[section]Pull name"
      echo "##[section]Compile time"
      echo ${{ upper(variables.Agent.HomeDirectory) }}
      echo ${{ upper(variables['Agent.HomeDirectory']) }}

      echo "##[section]Runtime"
      echo $[ upper("$(Agent.HomeDirectory)") ]
      echo $[ upper('$(Agent.HomeDirectory)') ]
      echo $[ upper($(Agent.HomeDirectory)) ]
      echo $[ upper(variables.AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY) ]
      echo $[ upper(variables['AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY']) ]
      echo $[ upper(variables.Agent.HomeDirectory) ]
      echo $[ upper(variables['Agent.HomeDirectory']) ]
      echo "##[endgroup]"
```

and output:

```
 ##[group]Static text
 ##[section]Compile time static text
 STATIC TEXT
 ##[section]Runtime static text
 ##[endgroup]
 ##[group]Static variable
 ##[section]Compile time
 TEST VAR
 TEST VAR
 ##[section]Runtime
 ##[endgroup]
 ##[group]Dynamic variable
 ##[section]Pull name
 ##[section]Compile time


 ##[section]Runtime
 ##[endgroup]
 /home/vsts/work/_temp/ccc35882-f832-4b6c-bf36-3985106238f5.sh: line 5: upper('Static text') : syntax error in expression (error token is "('Static text') ")
 /home/vsts/work/_temp/ccc35882-f832-4b6c-bf36-3985106238f5.sh: line 13: upper(test var) : syntax error in expression (error token is "(test var) ")
 /home/vsts/work/_temp/ccc35882-f832-4b6c-bf36-3985106238f5.sh: line 14: upper('test var') : syntax error in expression (error token is "('test var') ")
 /home/vsts/work/_temp/ccc35882-f832-4b6c-bf36-3985106238f5.sh: line 15: upper(test var) : syntax error in expression (error token is "(test var) ")
 /home/vsts/work/_temp/ccc35882-f832-4b6c-bf36-3985106238f5.sh: line 16: upper(variables.TEST_VAR) : syntax error in expression (error token is "(variables.TEST_VAR) ")
 /home/vsts/work/_temp/ccc35882-f832-4b6c-bf36-3985106238f5.sh: line 17: upper(variables['TEST_VAR']) : syntax error in expression (error token is "(variables['TEST_VAR']) ")
 /home/vsts/work/_temp/ccc35882-f832-4b6c-bf36-3985106238f5.sh: line 27: upper(/home/vsts/agents/2.190.0) : syntax error in expression (error token is "(/home/vsts/agents/2.190.0) ")
 /home/vsts/work/_temp/ccc35882-f832-4b6c-bf36-3985106238f5.sh: line 28: upper('/home/vsts/agents/2.190.0') : syntax error in expression (error token is "('/home/vsts/agents/2.190.0') ")
 /home/vsts/work/_temp/ccc35882-f832-4b6c-bf36-3985106238f5.sh: line 29: upper(/home/vsts/agents/2.190.0) : syntax error in expression (error token is "(/home/vsts/agents/2.190.0) ")
 /home/vsts/work/_temp/ccc35882-f832-4b6c-bf36-3985106238f5.sh: line 30: upper(variables.AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY) : syntax error in expression (error token is "(variables.AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY) ")
 /home/vsts/work/_temp/ccc35882-f832-4b6c-bf36-3985106238f5.sh: line 31: upper(variables['AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY']) : syntax error in expression (error token is "(variables['AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY']) ")
 /home/vsts/work/_temp/ccc35882-f832-4b6c-bf36-3985106238f5.sh: line 32: upper(variables.Agent.HomeDirectory) : syntax error in expression (error token is "(variables.Agent.HomeDirectory) ")
 /home/vsts/work/_temp/ccc35882-f832-4b6c-bf36-3985106238f5.sh: line 33: upper(variables['Agent.HomeDirectory']) : syntax error in expression (error token is "(variables['Agent.HomeDirectory']) ")
```

Maybe this is simple and obvious but I don't see solution.

Answer (score 1):

`${{ <expression> }}` is a compile time expression and `$(IMAGE)` is a runtime expressions and as this `$(IMAGE)` is not available at compilation.

Please check this part of [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops):

> The difference between runtime and compile time expression syntaxes is primarily what context is available. In a compile-time expression (${{  }}), you have access to parameters and statically defined variables. In a runtime expression ($[  ]), you have access to more variables but no parameters.